# Trying to make code asynchronous but without blocking my program is running away?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Writing a client / server program and previously was using calls like this:

`TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` `NetworkStream.Read()` `NetworkStream.Write()`

`TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` is working fine because its callback function is only called after a connection is made.

However, `BeginRead()` is not working as well. For some reason it executes and continues past it even when no data is sent.. Not sure what is going on. `NetworkStream.Read()` was blocking just fine but this isn't..

Here is the non-working thread that is created whenever a connection is established:

```
private void HandleClientCommunication(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    try
    {
        byte[] header = new byte[4];

        clientStream.BeginRead(header, 0, header.Length, Read, new StateData(clientStream, header)); // Runs even if no data is sent

        int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(header, 0); // Continues to this, even if no packets are sent..

        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength]; // dataLength is 0 still of course because none of the code is blocking

        clientStream.BeginRead(data, 0, dataLength, Read, new StateData(clientStream, data));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
    }

    // not relevant past here
}
```

Here's the Read method too. Not sure if it's needed to figure out the problem but I'll include it regardless:

```
private void Read(IAsyncResult async)
{
    StateData stateData = (StateData)async.AsyncState;

    stateData.BytesRead += stateData.Stream.EndRead(async);

    if (stateData.BytesRead < stateData.Bytes.Length)
    {
        stateData.Stream.BeginRead(stateData.Bytes, 0, stateData.Bytes.Length, Read, stateData);
    }
    else
    {
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stateData.Bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

So yeah I'm just trying to set up a client server interaction with asynchronous calls and have every "packet" include a header with the length of the data as an int and then right after that the data itself. Unfortunately, things seem to not be working and I'm not sure what the problem is.

Seems like I have to include some manual form of blocking but doesn't that defeat the purpose of using asynchronous calls? Why not just go back to regular synchronous blocking calls like `Read()` and `AcceptTcpClient()` at that point then?

I don't think I am fully understanding things here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, BeginRead() is not working as well. For some reason it executes and continues past it even when no data is sent.. Not sure what is going on. NetworkStream.Read() was blocking just fine but this isn't..

I think you've misunderstood what [`BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx) is meant to do. It's not *meant* to block - it issues an asynchronous read, executing the given callback when the read has completed. It's *meant* to return immediately - so it's no wonder your header data is empty.

Basically, any work which requires the data should be in the callback - not in the same method which calls `BeginRead`. Your first callback should convert the header data and then `BeginRead` again with a different callback to read the message data itself... although you should *also* bear in mind that any `Read`/`BeginRead` call may not read all the data you've asked for. You're *trying* to account for this in your callback, but you're not quite there - because you're always trying to fill the buffer *from the start* - which will overwrite any existing data. If you know how much data you're expecting overall and your buffer is that long, you should read into the buffer *starting at* how many bytes you've already read.

Note that C# 5 will make all of this a lot simpler - but if you can't wait until then, you may well find it easier to go back to blocking calls on multiple threads (one per client).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems as if the callback is executing even when nothing has been read though. The callback for BeginRead is executed right when the connection is made with *obviously* no data. Not sure how to proceed..

Comment: @Gabriel: That's probably because you're issuing a second BeginRead call asking for 0 bytes of data. It's probably the callback for *that* call which is being executed immediately. You really shouldn't be calling `BeginRead` again until the first read has finished anyway.

Comment: You explain things so well.. I think I'm going to buy your book.. lol

Comment: @GabrielJohnson: I hope you like it if you do - sorry that there isn't a simpler answer here; asynchrony is a pain at the moment. Read up on C# 5 though - it'll make things *so* much simpler :)